# CIDR Notation parser

Tags: java, parsing, unit-testing, ip-address

I created the following code to better understand CIDR notation.  Also to learn some of the Stream features in Java8.  I posted my unit tests too.

I'm interested in ways it might be improved especially by using Java8 features.  I reviewed the InetAddr class and realized it uses at array of bytes instead of ints.  I did not find that convenient.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This class accepts a String in CIDR format in the constructor
 * It calculates IP range and has methods for isInRange and count
 */
public class Cidr {
    public IPAddress ip;
    public int mask;

    // get an array of ints given a mask (like /24 /16 /8 etc...)
    int[] getIntMaskArray(int mask){
        int[] intArray = new int[4];
        String[] maskArray = getArrayBinaryStrings(mask, "1");
        for (int i = 0; i < maskArray.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(maskArray[i], 2);
        }
        return intArray;
    }

    String[] getArrayBinaryStrings(int mask, String fill){
        String s = "";
        String[] binArray = new String[4];
        String notFill = "0";
        if (fill.equals("0")){
            notFill = "1";
        }

        // loop of four, since there are four array elements:
        for (int x = 0 ; x < 4; x++){
            // 8 parts of each array element:
            for(int y = 0; y<8; y++){
                if(mask > 0){
                    s = s+fill;
                    mask = mask -1;
                } else {
                    s = s+notFill;
                }
            }
            binArray[x] = s;
            s = "";
        }
        return binArray;
    }

    public IPAddress getNetMask() throws InvalidIPException {
        // netmask is the mask converted to an IP Address:
        // can't use getArrayBinaryStrings because that returns array of binary strings!
        return new IPAddress(StringUtils.implode(getIntMaskArray(mask)));
    }

    IPAddress getAddress(){
        return this.ip;
    }

    public boolean isInRange(IPAddress ipAddress){
        return this.getHostMax().compareTo(ipAddress) > 0 && this.getHostMin().compareTo(ipAddress) < 0;
    }

    public long countHosts(){

        // host count should be hostMax - hostMin + 1
        return getHostMax().toDecimal() - getHostMin().toDecimal() + 1;
    }

    public IPAddress getHostMax(){
        // host max is one less than Broadcast
        return new IPAddress(getBroadcastAddress().toDecimal() - 1);
    }

    public IPAddress getHostMin(){
        // host min is simply adding one to the network address
        return new IPAddress(this.getNetworkAddress().toDecimal()+1);
    }

    public IPAddress getNetworkAddress(){
        String[] maskArray = getArrayBinaryStrings(mask, "1");
        return this.ip.and(getIpAddressFromBinary(maskArray));
    }

    public IPAddress getBroadcastAddress(){
        String[] invertedMaskArray = getArrayBinaryStrings(mask, "0");
        return getIpAddressFromBinary(invertedMaskArray).or(getNetworkAddress());
    }

    private IPAddress getIpAddressFromBinary(String[] maskArray) {
        String[] octetArray = new String[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < maskArray.length; i++) {
            octetArray[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(maskArray[i], 2));
        }
        try {
            return new IPAddress(String.join(".", octetArray));
        } catch (InvalidIPException iip){
            iip.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return list of all IP addresses in network defined by cidr
     */
    public ArrayList<IPAddress> ipList(){
        ArrayList<IPAddress> result = new ArrayList<IPAddress>();
        IPAddress hostMin = getHostMin();
        long longip = hostMin.toDecimal();
        while(longip <= getHostMax().toDecimal()){
            result.add(new IPAddress(longip));
            longip++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Cidr(String cidr){

        //divide string into IP + mask:
        String[] ip_mask = cidr.split("/");
        try {
            this.ip = new IPAddress(ip_mask[0]);
        } catch (InvalidIPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.mask = Integer.parseInt(ip_mask[1]);
    }
}
```

Here is the IPAddress class:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static com.company.StringUtils.padLeft;

public class IPAddress implements Comparable {

    private int[] octets;

    public IPAddress(int[] octets) {
        this.octets = octets;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object otherObject) {
        if (otherObject != null) {
            IPAddress secondIP = (IPAddress) otherObject;
            return (int) (this.toDecimal() - secondIP.toDecimal());
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        /* two ip addresses are equal if toStrings are equal: */
        return obj instanceof IPAddress && this.toString().equals(obj.toString());
    }

    public int[] getOctets() {
        return octets;
    }

    private boolean validIP(String ip){
        if(ip.split("\\.").length != 4){
            return false;
        }
        for (String octet : ip.split("\\.")){
            if (Integer.parseInt(octet) > 255 || Integer.parseInt(octet) < 0){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * create IP address using string
     * @param ip is an IP Address (ex: "10.10.232.133")
     */
    public IPAddress(String ip) throws InvalidIPException {
        // make sure the ip string is valid:
        // all the octets should fit into bytes
        if(!validIP(ip)){
            throw new InvalidIPException();

        }

        this.octets = Stream.of(ip.split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }

    /**
     * create IPAddress object using a decimal number
     * @param decimalRep decimal representation of IP address
     */
    public IPAddress(long decimalRep){

        String binString = padLeft(Long.toBinaryString(decimalRep),32,"0");
        // divide 32 character string into byte array:
        int[] octets = new int[4];
        int index = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        String newBinString;
        while (index < binString.length()){
            newBinString = binString.substring(index,index + 8);
            index = index + 8;
            int b = Integer.parseInt(newBinString, 2);
            octets[counter++] = b;
        }
        this.octets = octets;
    }

    public IPAddress and(IPAddress otherIP){

        int[] otherOctet = otherIP.getOctets();
        int[] thisOctets = this.getOctets();
        int[] newOctets = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < otherOctet.length; i++) {
            newOctets[i] = thisOctets[i] & otherOctet[i];
        }
        return new IPAddress(newOctets);
    }

    public IPAddress or(IPAddress otherIP){

        int[] otherOctet = otherIP.getOctets();
        int[] thisOctets = this.getOctets();
        int[] newOctets = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < otherOctet.length; i++) {
            newOctets[i] = otherOctet[i] | thisOctets[i];
        }
        return new IPAddress(newOctets);
    }

    public long toDecimal(){
        // turn each int into binary string
        String binString = "";
        for (int x : octets){
            //got to pad this:
            binString += padLeft(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
        }
        // turn it into a long:
        return Long.parseLong(binString,2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return StringUtils.implode(this.getOctets());
    }
}
```

StringUtils for manipulations that did not seem to belong in the other classes:

```
package com.company;

public class StringUtils {
    public static String padLeft (String input, int count, String pad){
        String output = "";
        for(int c = 0; c < count - input.length(); c++){
            output += pad;
        }
        return output + input;
    }

    public static String padLeft(String input){
        String pad = "0";
        return padLeft(input, 8, pad);
    }

    static String implode(int[] intArray){
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            int i1 = intArray[i];
            if (i != intArray.length -1 ) {
                result += i1 + ".";
            } else {
                result += i1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally, The Unit Tests:

```
package com.company;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class CidrTest {

    @Test(expected=InvalidIPException.class)
    public void testInvalidLarge() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ipOne = new IPAddress("10.20.33.500");
    }

    @Test(expected=InvalidIPException.class)
    public void testInvalidLetter() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ipTwo = new IPAddress("a.b.c.d");
    }

    @Test(expected=InvalidIPException.class)
    public void testInvalidSmall() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ipThree = new IPAddress("-1.10.-3.-4");
    }

    @Test(expected=InvalidIPException.class)
    public void testInvalidFormat() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ipFour = new IPAddress("20|33|3|0");
    }

    @Test(expected=InvalidIPException.class)
    public void testInvalidCount() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ipFour = new IPAddress("20.33.3.33.55");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCompareIP() throws Exception{
        IPAddress ipOne = new IPAddress("10.20.33.44");
        IPAddress ipTwo = new IPAddress("10.20.33.45");
        assertTrue(ipOne.compareTo(ipTwo) < 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsInRange() throws Exception {
        // an IP is in range if the ip is between hostMin and hostmax
        IPAddress ipThree = new IPAddress("10.20.33.28");
        Cidr cidr = new Cidr("10.20.33.4/24");
        assertTrue(cidr.isInRange(ipThree));
        // null address should never be in range.
        assertFalse(cidr.isInRange(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCountHosts() throws Exception {
        Cidr cdr = new Cidr("10.10.15.10/16");
        assertEquals(65534,cdr.countHosts());

        cdr = new Cidr("10.10.1.97/23");
        assertEquals(510,cdr.countHosts());

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNetMask() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ip = new IPAddress("255.255.0.0");
        assertEquals(ip, new Cidr("10.10.15.10/16").getNetMask());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNetworkAddress() throws Exception {
        IPAddress ip = new IPAddress("10.10.0.0");
        assertEquals(ip, new Cidr("10.10.15.10/16").getNetworkAddress());

        IPAddress ip2 = new IPAddress("10.10.0.0");
        Cidr cdr = new Cidr("10.10.1.97/23");
        assertEquals(ip2,cdr.getNetworkAddress());

        IPAddress net3 = new IPAddress("192.168.0.0");
        cdr = new Cidr("192.168.0.3/25");
        assertEquals(net3,cdr.getNetworkAddress());

        IPAddress net4 = new IPAddress("172.16.5.0");
        cdr = new Cidr("172.16.5.34/26");
        assertEquals(net4,cdr.getNetworkAddress());


    }
    @Test
    public void testGetBroadcast() throws Exception {
        // broadcast is inverted netmask ANDED with our network address:
        IPAddress broadcast = new IPAddress("10.10.255.255");
        assertEquals(broadcast,new Cidr("10.10.15.10/16").getBroadcastAddress());
        broadcast = new IPAddress("172.16.5.63");
        assertEquals(broadcast,new Cidr("172.16.5.34/26").getBroadcastAddress());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAddress() throws Exception {
        Cidr cdr = new Cidr("10.10.15.10/16");
        IPAddress ip = new IPAddress("10.10.15.10");
        assertEquals(ip, cdr.getAddress());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetHostMax() throws Exception {
        Cidr cdr = new Cidr("10.10.233.233/23");
        IPAddress min = new IPAddress("10.10.233.254");
        assertEquals(min,cdr.getHostMax());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetHostMin() throws Exception {
        Cidr cdr = new Cidr("10.10.233.233/23");
        IPAddress min = new IPAddress("10.10.232.1");
        assertEquals(min,cdr.getHostMin());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIpList() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<IPAddress> testArrayList = new ArrayList<IPAddress>();
        testArrayList.add(new IPAddress("10.10.233.233"));
        testArrayList.add(new IPAddress("10.10.233.234"));
        Cidr cdr = new Cidr("10.10.233.233/30");
        assertEquals(cdr.ipList(), testArrayList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Working on <s>String</s> <s>int[]</s> int

You're working on `String` and `int[]`. I have **absolutely no idea why**. The cool thing about CIDR notation is that it consists of 4 "octets". The value range 0-255 is exactly that of an unsigned byte.

Funnily enough, \$4 * 8 = 32\$ ... Interestingly that's exactly the size of an Integer. What you need to represent an IPv4 address is a single `int`. If you want to keep track of a subnet (which is a significantly different thing), you just need to add another `int` for the subnet mask.

Properly working with this you can then determine the first and last IP address in a subnet by the following rather easy process:

```
int lowestAddress = address & subnetMask;
int highestAddress = address | !subnetMask;
```

Unfortunately java is a little unfriendly if we look for unsigned primitive types, which means that trying to parse 255 into a byte results in an Exception.

As soon as you consider that working on a single integer is **significantly** faster (and more idiomatic), I think it becomes obvious you should consider reimplementing this by using byte-shifting, bitmasks and bitwise operators.

I strongly suggest you completely reimplement that class using just that representation.

**Nitpicks:**

- You're indenting by 2 spaces. It's usual to indent by 4 spaces in java. Then again you are consistent, soo ...
- You're using default visibility a lot. I don't like that, because I'd expect that to be explained by a comment. That visibility is not needed very often.